# Can't scrape metrics from activemq by jmx-exporter

Tags: java, activemq-classic, jmx-exporter

can't scrape metrics from activemq by jmx-exporter

i download the jmx exporter to my virtual machine and i follow the directions to run the command like this:

`java -javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar=8980:config.yaml -jar /usr/local/tomcat/apache-activemq/apache-activemq-5.8.0_56/bin/activemq.jar`

And i get some output info about the activemq.
then i try to curl it: 
`curl http://localhost:8980/metrics`.

And get the error: `curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`

I check out the process. And found there is no java process of the jvm-exporter.

Why? something i do wrong?

here is my config.yaml

```
[root@sz-7-centos162 test]# cat config.yaml 
{
        startDelaySeconds: 0,
        username: admin,
        password: admin,
        jmxUrl: "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi",
        ssl: false,
        lowercaseOutputName: false,
        lowercaseOutputLabelNames: false
}
```

I expect curl http://localhost:8980/metrics to get the metrics,but actual it just display me some info about activemq but do nothing.
all the output info and my operate are paste below:

```
[root@sz-7-centos162 test]# java -javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar=8980:config.yaml -jar /usr/local/tomcat/apache-activemq/apache-activemq-5.8.0_56/bin/activemq.jar
Java Runtime: Oracle Corporation 1.8.0_51 /usr/jdk1.8.0_51/jre
  Heap sizes: current=243712k  free=233469k  max=3608576k
    JVM args: -javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar=8980:config.yaml
Extensions classpath:
  [/usr/local/tomcat/apache-activemq/apache-activemq-5.8.0_56/lib,/usr/local/tomcat/apache-activemq/apache-activemq-5.8.0_56/lib/camel,/usr/local/tomcat/apache-activemq/apache-activemq-5.8.0_56/lib/optional,/usr/local/tomcat/apache-activemq/apache-activemq-5.8.0_56/lib/web,/usr/local/tomcat/apache-activemq/apache-activemq-5.8.0_56/lib/extra]
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: /usr/local/tomcat/apache-activemq/apache-activemq-5.8.0_56
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: /usr/local/tomcat/apache-activemq/apache-activemq-5.8.0_56
ACTIVEMQ_CONF: /usr/local/tomcat/apache-activemq/apache-activemq-5.8.0_56/conf
ACTIVEMQ_DATA: /usr/local/tomcat/apache-activemq/apache-activemq-5.8.0_56/data
Usage: Main [--extdir <dir>] [task] [task-options] [task data]

Tasks:
    browse                   - Display selected messages in a specified destination.
    bstat                    - Performs a predefined query that displays useful statistics regarding the specified broker
    create                   - Creates a runnable broker instance in the specified path.
    decrypt                  - Decrypts given text
    encrypt                  - Encrypts given text
    export                   - Exports a stopped brokers data files to an archive file
    list                     - Lists all available brokers in the specified JMX context
    purge                    - Delete selected destination's messages that matches the message selector
    query                    - Display selected broker component's attributes and statistics.
    start                    - Creates and starts a broker using a configuration file, or a broker URI.
    stop                     - Stops a running broker specified by the broker name.

Task Options (Options specific to each task):
    --extdir <dir>  - Add the jar files in the directory to the classpath.
    --version       - Display the version information.
    -h,-?,--help    - Display this help information. To display task specific help, use Main [task] -h,-?,--help

Task Data:
    - Information needed by each specific task.

JMX system property options:
    -Dactivemq.jmx.url=<jmx service uri> (default is: 'service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi')
    -Dactivemq.jmx.user=<user name>
    -Dactivemq.jmx.password=<password>


[root@sz-7-centos162 test]# curl http://localhost:8980/metrics
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
[root@sz-7-centos162 test]# ps -ef|grep javaagent
root     23739 21179  0 23:46 pts/0    00:00:00 grep javaagent
[root@sz-7-centos162 test]# cat config.yaml 
{
        startDelaySeconds: 0,
        username: admin,
        password: admin,
        jmxUrl: "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi",
        ssl: false,
        lowercaseOutputName: false,
        lowercaseOutputLabelNames: false
}
[root@sz-7-centos162 test]# ll
total 368
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    252 Aug 26 23:19 config.yaml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 370075 Aug 26 17:45 jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar
[root@sz-7-centos162 test]#
```

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help others who may have this same question in the future. If not, please elaborate as to why. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually starting the ActiveMQ broker. That's why it prints all that information about what commands are available, e.g.:

```
Usage: Main [--extdir <dir>] [task] [task-options] [task data]

Tasks:
    browse                   - Display selected messages in a specified destination.
    bstat                    - Performs a predefined query that displays useful statistics regarding the specified broker
    create                   - Creates a runnable broker instance in the specified path.
    decrypt                  - Decrypts given text
    encrypt                  - Encrypts given text
    export                   - Exports a stopped brokers data files to an archive file
    list                     - Lists all available brokers in the specified JMX context
    purge                    - Delete selected destination's messages that matches the message selector
    query                    - Display selected broker component's attributes and statistics.
    start                    - Creates and starts a broker using a configuration file, or a broker URI.
    stop                     - Stops a running broker specified by the broker name.

Task Options (Options specific to each task):
    --extdir <dir>  - Add the jar files in the directory to the classpath.
    --version       - Display the version information.
    -h,-?,--help    - Display this help information. To display task specific help, use Main [task] -h,-?,--help

Task Data:
    - Information needed by each specific task.
```

You'll notice that one of those commands is `start`. This is the command you need to run to actually start a broker.

Aside from that, your `config.yaml` doesn't have any `rules` defined to tell the exporter what MBeans to scrape & export. You can find example rules for various application [here](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/tree/master/example_configs). Unfortunately there isn't one for ActiveMQ 5.x so you'll need to work one up.

Aside from that you might consider [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) (the next generation of ActiveMQ broker). It has a [plugin architecture to export metrics](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/metrics.html), and [Prometheus plugin](https://github.com/jbertram/artemis-prometheus-metrics-plugin) implementation so there's no need to use the JMX exporter and configure rules.

Comment: Hi，@JustinBertram  Before i run the start command. my broker is being running. in addition, our production use this version. so, it cannot be repiaced temporarily. about the config.yaml, the official website explains that if not configured it will collected all the metrics by default. I consider that gathered all the metrics first, then I'll write the rules to filter out what i don't need

Comment: If the broker is already running why are you effectively running `java  -jar activemq.jar`? The `javaagent` needs to be set on the ActiveMQ broker process not on some other random process.

Comment: Point taken about not *necessarily* needing rules, but you'll want them eventually so it's worth pointing out.